# How to change default text direction in Power Point 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, right-to-left

My PowerPoint's default text direction is right to left.

How can I change it to left to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some VBA to achieve this. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA editor, select menu *Insert > Module* and paste the following code

```vb
Sub ResetLeftToRight()

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    ' make sure slide sorter reads left to right    
    ActivePresentation.LayoutDirection = ppDirectionLeftToRight

    ' then fix each of the text boxes
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            On Error Resume Next
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    WIth oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
                         .TextDirection = ppDirectionLeftToRight
                    End With 
                End If
            End If
        Next    ' shape
    Next    ' slide

End Sub
```

After all press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run.

The script above resets each textbox's text direction. It also resets the interface if it's currently in right-to-left like this

[image: Powerpoint RTL UI]

[image: Powerpoint RTL list UI]

Comment: Thanks. It's a surprise that there's no setting in PowerPoint for this.

Comment: It has reset the interface, however the Text direction is still right to left.

Comment: this works for the current texts on the presentation. I haven't found the way to change the default setting

Comment: The problem is that text are still right to left

Comment: Thanks, Lưu Vĩnh Phúc. It helped. I needed to restart Power Point for several times.