# Right-to-Left on English display

Tags: display, windows-10, right-to-left, english

I have Windows 10 in English, but the Left-to-Right isn't so comfortable for me.
How can I switch to Right-to-Left but stay with the English language as the main display language of the system?

Comment: English isn't a right to left language though.

Comment: There isn't any way so I can be on RTL and still on English?

Comment: You don't want English *text* to go RTL, ?thgiR (Not even just word by word, I assume?) So just the placing of the components (buttons, menus, taskbar) should change?

Comment: [Windows Form has a property to select left-to-right to right-to-left layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d3337xw%28VS.80%29.aspx) but it depends on each application to set that. For example with [powerpoint you can do like this](https://superuser.com/q/662658/241386)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a *word processor* such as MS Word or LibreOffice, you can define a block of text or a whole document as right-to-left, and change the keyboard layout for that section as well. For example, to use Arabic, Farsi or Hebrew in LibreOffice, see [*How to setup LibreOffice for Arabic and Persian?*](http://alefba.us/libreoffice-arabic-persian) and [*Edit Hebrew with LibreOffice*](http://opensiddur.org/tools/editing-layout/).

This will not help with text entry in CMD, browsers etc., though.

Answer (score 1):

Add a keyboard layout (in Regional settings).

Settings - Time and Language - Region and Language - Add a language.

This does not change the UI language, only offers you more languages (including left to right languages) to use in applications (such as MS Word).

Answer (score 0):

I've been employing the following method for years:

[Reversed Taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNMtZ.png), [Reversed Explorer Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3K3K.png)

Using [Microsoft Locale Editor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41158), I took my current locale and edited *one* setting (enabling RTL for that locale).  Then, export your new locale to an `.msi` installer and run it.  Afterwards, restart File Explorer.